# cross domain issue in making application offline using HTML5

Tags: html, offline-caching

I have 2 servers. One which serves static content (abc server) and the other is the application server (def).

The static contents(images,css, js) are served from the assets (apache server) while the application(index.html) is served from a different server.

How do I make the application offline in this case using manifest file.

Right now my manifest file looks like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
http://abc.com/user.js
http://abc.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
```

And in the index.html file located on the def server

```
<html manifest="test.appcache">
```

Console output

> Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest
>   http://def.com/test.appcache Application Cache Checking event

The static content doesnt get cached as seen from the console.

Comment: whether http://def.com/test.appcache is your original cache  file

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Sorry actually according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy currently the only browser that allows for Cross-Domain caching is Chrome and that is only because they are willfully not adhering to the same origin policy. If you want to make your offline site exclusively for chrome users you can do dual servers, otherwise you'll have to stick with one until the different browsers come up with a new policy.

Comment: Oh okay. So this means this app will work offline only in chrome correct?

Comment: Yep, Chrome doesn't follow the specification in this regard. Over SSL, Chrome will load resources from different origins so long as they are still served over SSL

Comment: Thanks. One of the developer just told me that it worked on the safari browser, but on the ipad (using safari). Is there any documentation which I can confirm this?